# What is SAP, and what are it's common applications?

Tags: sap

Can someone just give me a quick run through of what SAP is. I googled it but there are too many different versions of it so I'm not sure where exactly to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SAP is a German software development
>   and consulting corporation, which
>   provides enterprise software
>   applications and support to businesses
>   of all sizes globally. Headquartered
>   in Walldorf, Germany, with regional
>   offices around the world, SAP is the
>   largest software enterprise in Europe
>   and the fourth largest software
>   enterprise in the world as of 2009.[2](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/go/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/library/elearning/other-topics/community/scn-guide/Walk-On-001b/index.html)
>   The company's best known product is
>   its SAP Enterprise Resource Planning
>   (SAP ERP) software.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_AG

**Using It:**

**[SAP Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_Implementation)**
**[SAP COMMUNITY NETWORK](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/go/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/library/elearning/other-topics/community/scn-guide/Walk-On-001b/index.html)**

Answer (score 2):

SAP is a provider of BI and CRM applications. PeopleSoft, SalesForce would be similar products